# Class method and variable with same name, compile error in C++ not in Java?

Tags: java, c++

```
class Test {

      bool isVal() const {
          return isVal;
      }

  private:

      bool isVal;
};
```

On Compiling this file it says

> testClass.cpp:9: declaration of `bool
>   Test::isVal'
>
> testClass.cpp:3: conflicts with
>   previous declaration `bool
>   Test::isVal()'

Although the same would work for java

```
class Test {

  private boolean isVal;

  public boolean isVal() {
      return isVal;
  }

}
```

Why does the compile error occur in C++ not in Java?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Because C++ is not Java. You can take the address of a member:

```
&Test::isVal
```

So you can't have two members have the same name, except that you can overload member functions. Even if you could disambiguate that by some kind of cast, the next problem would already arise at other places.

In C++, a lot of people including me usually call data members specially, like putting a `m` before their name. This avoids the problem:

```
class Test {
public:
    bool IsVal() const { return mIsVal; }
private:
    bool mIsVal;
};
```

Comment: ... and, under the covers, the functions don't really have the same name anyway, since they're distinguished by class and argument signature.

Comment: (IIRC) Microsoft did the m_ thing first.  I'm currently maintaining code that does it, but I'm not a fan.  I'm OK with trailing underscore for private data members but for some reason I don't like the m_ prefix.

Comment: Great. Now should I complain about having getter functions? :)

Comment: I like your comment of "Because C++ is not Java.".

Answer (score 16):

C++ applies name mangling to function names and global variables. Local variables are not mangled. The problem arises because in C you can access the address of a variable or a function (thus in C++ as well) e.g. :

```
struct noob{
    bool noobvar;
    void noobvar(){};
};
```

One can say, why not apply name mangling to local variables as well and then have an internal local representation such as

```
bool __noobvar_avar;
void __noobvar_void_fun;
```

and suppose that they receive the addresses during execution 0x000A and 0x00C0 respectively.

However if we write somewhere in the code:

```
&noob::noobvar
```

What should the program do ?

1. return the address of the variable noobvar , i.e. 0x000A
2. return the addres of the noobvar function , i.e. 0x00C0

You can see that since in C , and therefore in C++ , you can issue an "address of", it is not legal to have variables and functions with the same name within the same scope of resolution.

Answer (score 10):

Functions in c/c++ are just pointers to a location in memory where the code is located, isVal (as a boolean) and isVal (as a function) are therefore ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

The quick answer is "because that's the way C++ works."  C++ doesn't have a separate name space for member variables and member functions (ie, "methods") where Java (apparently, as I haven't tried this) does.

In any case, remember the old story about the guy who went to a doctor and said "Doc, it hurts when I do *this*."  To which the doctor replied "well, don't *do* that!"  This is a language peculiarity on its way to becoming a Dumb Programmer Trick.

Comment: I don't think the dumb programmer can do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

The following section from the C++ Draft Standard N3337 specifies when a name can be overloaded.

> **13 Overloading**
>
> 1 When two or more different declarations are specified for a single name in the same scope, that name is said to be *overloaded*. By extension, two declarations in the same scope that declare the same name but with different types are called *overloaded declarations*. Only function and function template declarations can be overloaded; variable and type declarations cannot be overloaded.

When you define a class as:

```
class Test {

      bool isVal() const {
          return isVal;
      }

  private:

      bool isVal;
};
```

you are overloading the name `isVal` within the scope of the class. Such an overload is allowed only when `isVal` is a member function. It is not allowed when `isVal` is a member variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really need it, you can do it:

```
#include <iostream>

struct TestBase {
      bool isVal;
};

struct Test : TestBase {
      bool isVal() const {
          return TestBase::isVal;
      }
};

int main() {
  Test t;
  std::cout << static_cast<TestBase&>(t).isVal << std::endl;
  std::cout << t.isVal() << std::endl;
}
```

https://replit.com/@Konard/SameNameVariableAndFunction#main.cpp

This way you have members with the same name, but with different addresses. Though `isVal` variable is hidden by `isVal` function in the derived struct, you still can access this variable if you cast your struct to `TestBase` reference.

Answer (score -4):

If you have some reason to use same names for variable and method (maybe reduce naming for things have almost same purpose,etc??), I suggest that just naming them with different case:

```
class Test 
{
    private bool isVal;
    public bool ISVAL() 
    {   return isVal;  }
}
```

Comment: I don't. Caps for member functions? Ew.

Comment: A common naming style I've seen in C++ programs is to name functions in camelCase, and variables in lowercase. In my opinion, using a lesser-known naming style might confuse some readers.