# G++ compiler cannot distinguish variable and function with the same name?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, naming-conventions, method-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Class method and variable with same name, compile error in C++ not in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467815/class-method-and-variable-with-same-name-compile-error-in-c-not-in-java)

The G++ compiler would complain when my class member name and member function name are the same. It seems that whenever a variable name happens to be the same as a function name, the compiler would complain.

In Java, it is not the case. I just wonder why the G++ compiler cannot distinguish a variable name from a function name since the function name always comes with a pair of parenthesis.

Comment: A more useful question would be to include a sample of code that doesn't compile and ask us why it doesn't compile. C++ and C have rules. These are independent, and different, from the Java rules. C, C++ and Java are three different programming languages.

Comment: Actually you can have basically the same problem in Java as well (classes vs. fields in that case). In java it's solved by a) using sensible naming conventions and b) umn I think the field has precedence in case of ambiguities.

Comment: @Voo BTW, what does "umn" mean in your comment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
struct Callable
{
    void operator()() const { }
};

struct Test
{
    void Call() { }
    Callable Call;
};

int main()
{
    Test x;
    x.Call(); // To which 'Call' does this refer?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's two reasons:

- The variable might overload `operator()`
- One might take the address of, or create references the function (using its name without associated function call `()`)

In the first case, what would `variable()` do? in the second, the compiler would have to determine the correct operation by the return type of an operation - which C++ does not allow for all sorts of reasons.