# Using a simple class in c++, not working?

Tags: c++, class

I found a begginers c++ challenge I wanted to try. However, the following code is saying that it contains erros when I compile it. If I try to take 1 line at a time, it exits in the first class definition at the end... I have no idea what's wrong :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Polynomial {
    int a, b, c, functionValue;

public:
    Polynomial (int, int, int);
    static void functionValue(Polynomial);
};

Polynomial::Polynomial (int x, int y, int z) {
    a = x;
    b = y;
    c = z;
}

void Polynomial::functionValue(Polynomial x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        x.functionValue = x.a * pow(i, 2) + x.b * i + x.c;
        cout << "The value of the function for x = "
             << i << " is " << x.functionValue;
    }
}

int main () {
    Polynomial poly (2, 3, 5);
    Polynomial::functionValue(poly);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why the formatting is so poor. Here is a [pastebin link.](http://pastebin.com/XZ7UdDvv)

(Edit: My fault, I edited over a previous edit and accidentally removed these - BoBTFish)

Compiler errors:

```
'Polynomial::functionValue' : redefinition; previous definition was 'data member' 'see declaration of 'Polynomial::functionValue'
'Polynomial::functionValue' : not a function' 'illegal reference to non-static member 'Polynomial::functionValue'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what are the compiler errors?

Comment: Sorry, will update OP.

Comment: To start with, could you please provide the _error_ you're getting? It will be much easier to see what the errors are. Also please indicate in the source where the errors are.

Comment: Also, the `functionValue` function will set the `functionValue` variable _on a copy_! The member variable in the `poly` object will **not** be set.

Comment: how are you assigning a value to functionValue when it is a function?

Comment: In addition to the problems with `functionValue` pointed out by others, you will need to `#include <cmath>` to get `pow`.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582477/g-compiler-cannot-distinguish-variable-and-function-with-the-same-name) discussion on a similar topic

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Surprised I get so many downvotes for not being good at C++. What should I do differently next time I have a problem?

Comment: @wizH Maybe because you didnt add the error messages (I havent downvoted). Error messages reveal a lot of problems and most of the time pinpoint to exactly what the problem is

Comment: I just started programming again yesterday, so wasn't really in the loop... Added it a few minutes later, though... Anyways, I fixed the beginner mistake from your answers. Not really a nice way of being introduced to the community... Thanks anyways!

Comment: accept one of those answers, whichever helped you.

Comment: Oh! I saw the edit for your post now. It seems @BobTFish missed the error out while making the edit

Comment: I'm been spamming that button, but it said I had to wait a couple of minutes :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Think we were editing at the same time and I saved over it...

Comment: @wizH: +1 Because the question is good as it stands. Even if the error message points to the problem, without experience it can be hard for beginners to understand them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have `functionValue` as variable and also as function.

Answer (score 3):

`functionValue` is used twice in two different ways, once as an integer the other as a static function.

Answer (score 1):

functionValue can be any of the member or the function name. You should rename any of those.

Also what is the need of making the function static.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that there is also a variable named `functionValue`.

I suggest you install an alternative C/C++ compiler - `Clang`. Clang gives more details about why and where the possible errors are.

For example, I compiled your code with `Clang`, which gives me following information.

```
test.cc:10:17: error: redefinition of 'functionValue' as different kind of symbol
    static void functionValue(Polynomial);
                ^
test.cc:6:18: note: previous definition is here
    int a, b, c, functionValue;
                 ^
test.cc:19:18: error: redefinition of 'functionValue' as different kind of symbol
void Polynomial::functionValue(Polynomial x) {
                 ^
test.cc:6:18: note: previous definition is here
    int a, b, c, functionValue;
```

These give the accurate position of possible errors.

Clang is really helpful for beginners.