# Why variables and functions cannot have same name?

Tags: c++

I read an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467815/class-method-and-variable-with-same-name-compile-error-in-c-not-in-java) explains why function and variable cannot have same name, most of those people says it's because if I try to get address of those things, compiler will not understand which I want, but in C++, overload function is valid, and if I try to get address of overloaded function, it will generate an error, so why not just generate an error while getting variable and function have same name, could anyone tell me why C++ standard not allowed it?

Comment: You can also overload `operator()` at least then you can't disambiguate functions and variables.

Comment: why should it be allowed? Consider for example that you can overload a function to take eitehr a "normal variable" or a function as parameter. Then you need to disambiguate which one to call

Comment: @churill Thank for your comment, this is what I want.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't need to generate an error when trying to get the address of variables and functions with the same name, because [you cannot *have* variables and functions with the same name in the same scope](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd30c8154c21d987).

If one is in a tighter scope, and *hides* the other, then there is no conflict, and no reason to produce an error.

Trying to take the address of an overloaded function without providing a resolution hint produces an error because there is literally nothing else the compiler can do; it doesn't know which function you're talking about.

Comment: If you read the original question you'll see that it wasn't about whether it's possible or not, but why it's not allowed by the standard.

Comment: @IlCapitano If you read the answer, you'll see that this _is_ why it's not allowed by the standard.

Comment: The only part of your answer which tries to explain why is the last paragraph, which states that without an explicit cast, taking the address of an overloaded function produces an error.  The question also talks about this behaviour, asking why the same couldn't be done for function and variable name collision.

Comment: @IlCapitano Feel free to write an answer.